# Is there a standard way to create a command history "effect" for "edit" fields in Windows?

Tags: winapi

Can I achieve the command history effect (i.e. up arrow = previous issued command, down arrow = next command - like in `cmd.exe`, for example) for `edit` fields (windows created with CreateWindow) in Win32 using a standard approach, or do I have to implement my own?

Comment: Never heard of the term "console cache". What you describe is usually described as "command history"

Comment: @oefe Yep, that's what I meant, I didn't know the term. Updating, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows API does not have equivalent functionality. There is no style setting for an edit control that tells it to maintain history, and there's no standard control with such functionality that you can attach to an edit control.

I've also never seen a third party control that includes such functionality. Although it's possible that one does exist.

Comment: I'll just implement my own one then. Thanks :)